# How much USD is there in total?

Tags: united-states, federal-reserve, money-supply

If I hypothetically took all of the USD out there in physical currency and in people's savings/checking account then how much would I have?

I suppose this would also include any liquid cash that corporations are holding like the cash in a cash register and the money they have in corporate savings accounts.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about the Money supply, this is a statistic kept by the [US Federal reserve](https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h6/current/default.htm):

> - M1 consists of (1) currency outside the U.S. Treasury, Federal Reserve Banks, and the vaults of depository institutions; (2)
>   traveler's checks of nonbank issuers; (3) demand deposits at
>   commercial banks (excluding those amounts held by depository
>   institutions, the U.S. government, and foreign banks and official
>   institutions) less cash items in the process of collection and Federal
>   Reserve float; and (4) other checkable deposits (OCDs), consisting of
>   negotiable order of withdrawal (NOW) and automatic transfer service
>   (ATS) accounts at depository institutions, credit union share draft
>   accounts, and demand deposits at thrift institutions. Seasonally
>   adjusted M1 is constructed by summing currency, traveler's checks,
>   demand deposits, and OCDs, each seasonally adjusted separately.
> - M2 consists of M1 plus (1) savings deposits (including money market deposit accounts); (2) small-denomination time deposits (time
>   deposits in amounts of less than $100,000), less individual retirement
>   account (IRA) and Keogh balances at depository institutions; and (3)
>   balances in retail money market mutual funds, less IRA and Keogh
>   balances at money market mutual funds. Seasonally adjusted M2 is
>   constructed by summing savings deposits, small-denomination time
>   deposits, and retail money funds, each seasonally adjusted separately,
>   and adding this result to seasonally adjusted M1.

It appears they update the numbers every week.